# once again giving the syntax error for insert into query

Tags: c#

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Samples\\login.mdb";
string uname, pass;
uname = textBox1.Text;
pass = textBox2.Text; 

OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
myConnection.Open();

string query = "insert into LOGIN_TABLE (UserName, Password) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "') ";

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
//myCommand.CommandText = query;
OleDbParameter myParm = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
myParm.Value = textBox1.Text;

myParm = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs for [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not
>   support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a
>   stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set
>   to Text. In this case, the question
>   mark (?) placeholder must be used.

There's an example on the same page.

However, you're not even *using* parameters in your SQL query. You're inviting a SQL injection attack by embedding the user input directly into the SQL and then *also* adding parameters.

Your query should just be:

```
String query = "insert into LOGIN_TABLE (UserName, Password) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

It looks like you *can* still give parameters names, even if they're not used - so just the change above may be enough.

EDIT: Is it possible that UserName or Password are reserved names? Try escaping them - I know in SQL Server it would be `[UserName], [Password]` but I don't know if that's true in Access. What happens if you try to execute the same SQL in Access, by the way?

Comment: String query = "insert into LOGIN_TABLE (UserName, Password) VALUES (?, ?)";
 for this also its giving same error!!!

Comment: @santhosh: Has it occurred to you that it might help if you told us what the error is?

Comment: @jon:  its giving error as syntax error in insert query for
String query = "insert into LOGIN_TABLE (UserName, Password) VALUES (?, ?)";

Comment: @santhosh: With really *no* more detail than "syntax error"? When do you get the error? Where does it appear?

Comment: @jon: it gives error in a error wind the error is Unhandled exception has occured in your appliction 

Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement

Comment: Add a try/catch around that code, inspect the exception INCLUDING InnerExceptions and add the messages and any further hints the exceptions might give to the question. THEN we might be able to help you further.

Answer (score -1):

The data you are passing as parameters might have single-quotes, ', in it.
Try this textBox2.Text.Replace("'","''") when assigning values to the parameters.

One more thing, it is not necessary to use parameters when handling simple texts and numbers in simple queries.

Comment: DO use parameters, then you will not be troubled by quotes and such. Also it's good to get into the habit of using then - then you won't forget it where it can hurt.

Answer (score -1):

Your query should be like this.

```
string query = "insert into LOGIN_TABLE (UserName, Password) VALUES ( @uname, @pass )";
```

Now after that write your code, and everything will be work for you.

Whenever you are reading value from textbox, use Trim() as `textBox.Text.Trim()`.
Sorry it will be working for SqlConnection.

Thanks